# GCP Dataflow vs Cloud Functions to automate scrapping output and file-on-cloud merge into JSON format to insert in DB

Tags: mongodb, web-scraping, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I have two sources:

1. A csv that will be uploaded to a cloud storage service, probably GCP Cloud Storage.
2. The output of a scrapping process done with Python.

When a user updates 1) (the cloud stored file) an event should be triggered to execute 2) (the scrapping process) and then some transformation should take place in order to merge these two sources into one in a JSON format. Finally, the content of this JSON file should be stored in a DB of easy access and low cost. The files the user will update are of max 5MB and the updates will take place once weekly.

From what I've read, I can use GCP Cloud Functions to accomplish this whole process or I can use Dataflow too. I've even considered using both. I've also thought of using MongoDB to store the JSON objects of the two sources final merge.

Why should I use Cloud Functions, Dataflow or both? What are your thoughts on the DB? I'm open to different approaches. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding de use of Cloud Functions and Dataflow. In your case I will go for Cloud Functions as you don't have a big volume of data. Dataflow is more complex, more expensive and you will have to use Apache Beam. If you are confortable with python and having into consideration your scenario I will choose Cloud Functions. Easy, convenient...
To trigger a Cloud Functions when Cloud Storage object is updated you will have to configure the triggers. Pretty easy.
https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/storage

Regarding the DB. MongoDB is a good option but if you wanth something quick an inexpensive consider [DataStore](https://cloud.google.com/datastore)

As a managed service it will make your life easy with a lot of native integrations. Also it has a very interesting free tier.